# CiviVolunteer Not Working After CiviCRM 5.5.2 Upgrade

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer, 5.0

I just updated CiviCRM from 5.4 to 5.5.2, and now when I click on Volunteer -> Manage Volunteer Projects, or Volunteers -> New Volunteer Project, it just dumps me back to the dashboard, and I don't see any errors in the logs. It was working fine on CiviCRM 5.4.

Is CiviVolunteer not compatible with CiviCRM 5.5.2? This is on WordPress, and the version of CiviVolunteer I have installed is 4.7.31-2.3.1.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matt,

Can you perform CiviCRM cleanup cache? This usually happens when menu is not registered. You can do this by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup caches and reset paths and then click on cleanup cache. Or you can just hit the url with civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Cleanup caches did the trick. Thanks! CiviCRM has a really great community -- very knowledgeable and helpful!

Comment: Always welcome. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Civi 5.3.1 under Drupal, so I cannot tell you if Volunteer is compatible with 5.4 under WordPress. But I have a vague recollection of having your symptom after upgrading Civi some months ago. I believe the problem was solved by deleting the contents of the templates_c directory, which in WordPress is found under /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/.